# Locating optional element in Playwright

Tags: playwright

I'm using Playwright for web scraping and I currently need to find a certain description text. I know there doesn't have to be a description text on each page I scrape from that website so I want it to be "optional".

I've solved it and it works but I think it's ugly and I want to know if there is a better way?

```js
let description: string | undefined;
try {
  const locator = page.locator(".svtmat_recipe__preamble");
  await locator.waitFor({ timeout: 3000 });
  description = (await locator.textContent()) ?? undefined;
} catch {}
```

Comment: No language tag?

Answer (score 3):

Your code looks good, but I would change it a little bit:

```js
// Because 'textContent' method returns promise of string | null. 
// So you don't need to use the 'nullish coalescing' operator (??)
let description: string | null;

try {
  const locator = page.locator(".svtmat_recipe__preamble");
  // also you can pass { timeout: 3000 } to the 'textContent' method to wait for it
  description = await locator.textContent({ timeout: 3000 })
} catch {}
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends, weather you need to wait "some time" for that locator to be present in the DOM.

```
await page.isVisible("text='yourText'")
```

or

```
if(await page.locator(your_selector).count()>0)
```

But in case you need to wait for element to be present in DOM, try catch seems to be one of the appropriate solutions, since waitForSelector is throwing exepction if timeout is reached.

Answer (score 0):

Remember locator will not wait for any selector to appear. So you might need to await for the result.

```
const selector = '.svtmat_recipe__preamble'
await page.waitForSelector(selector)
const el = await page.locator(foo).count()
console.log(el)
```